# Child_added subscription seems to download entire dataset

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a large data set (~100k entries), that is being subscribed to using the 'child_added' event. Using node 7 and firebase 3.6.1, doing this seems to download the entire 100k entries before a single child_added event is fired.

Memory consumption grows significantly for a few dozen seconds, and then all child_added events are fired swiftly after each other.

This is slow:

```
require('firebase').
initializeApp({databaseURL: 'https://someproject.firebaseio.com'}).
database().ref('data').
on('child_added', (snap) => console.log(snap.key));
```

Limiting is still fast (few seconds delay):

```
require('firebase').
initializeApp({databaseURL: 'https://someproject.firebaseio.com'}).
database().ref('data').limitToFirst(10).
on('child_added', (snap) => console.log(snap.key));
```

Given the streaming nature of Firebase, I assume it is not intended behaviour for child_added subscriptions to download the entire data set to the client before anything is done.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Although that in the *child_added* section extracted from [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-added) it says:

> The **child_added** event is typically used when retrieving a list of items from the database. Unlike value which returns the entire contents of the location, child_added is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data. For ordering purposes, it is also passed a second argument containing the key of the previous child.

[At the first lines](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) in that page, we can found this:

> Data stored in a Firebase Realtime Database is retrieved by attaching an asynchronous listener to a database reference. **The listener will be triggered once for the initial state of the data and again anytime the data changes.**

Seems to be its normal behaviour. It first retrieves all the data.

Comment: This does not explain why the entire data set is downloaded first, before any of the child_added events are fired. Expected behaviour would be to see those events fire as the entries are being downloaded, or at least in smaller batches.

I modified the code examples, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: This goes against what Firebase was built to do (streaming in data), so I'm having a hard time accepting that this is truly intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the same situation, waiting nearly 40 seconds for the first child to fire. The only solution I could come up with was to get the keys using Firebase rest API and shallow query parameter, then loop over each key and call Firebase. Here is basically what I did.

```
`
    console.log('start', Date.now());
    fetch('https://[firebase_app].firebaseio.com/[your_path].json?shallow=true')
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(j) {
        Object.keys(j).forEach(function (key) {
                console.log(key, 'start', Date.now());
                firebase_reference.child(key).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
                    console.log(key, Date.now());
                    //now you have the first response without waiting for everything.
                });
        });
    });`
```

I know this doesn't answer your question about child_added functionality, but it does what you would expect to happen with child_added. I am going to submit a feature request to Firebase and link this SO question.